# Android studio - how can I save a textView's text as a PNG image (with it's font, color, and font size)?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, storage

I researched a lot on the internet but no use.
I am very new to Android programming and java.
I wrote a simple program in Android studio that lets you write a text in a cool font I set, optionally the user can chose color and font size.
I want to save this text, with its font, font size, and font color; as an image viewable with any galley application. I tried lots of things spent hours on it but universe is still against me.
I managed to create a bitmap image, and I can view it in an ImageView,but I can't save it to storage.
Can someone please explain this very simply ? Im very new to both Android and Java.

Comment: All you need is draw view's (in this case your TextView) content to Bitmap, and save to storage. Try [this](https://gist.github.com/savaskoc/ea401c44d9636b39ff09)

PS: saveImageToInternalStorage is taken from answer below.

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {

    try {
        // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to
        // the OutputStream
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
        return true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }  
}
```

Comment: I got this error: error: cannot find symbol variable context